# Compositor spitting out inconsistent noise

Tags: compositing-nodes

So I have a scene that I'm playing around with, and it was working exactly how I wanted until I rendered an animation. About ten of the frames had some odd white blocks appear on a certain portion of the scene, so I re-rendered them and they went away. Guess my computer was dying or something. Then I was down to the last three frames I had to re-render, and the white blocks didn't go away - they started appearing in more places.

It's not consistent (which makes me even more confused), but for these few frames I couldn't get the original white blocks to go away. [Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMdvI.jpg). It's actually kinda funny - I checked the color values in the image viewer, and every channel is in the trillions. Anybody know what could be wrong?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: I guess you're using your graphics card for rendering. I had the same problems sometimes. The GC is just not able to finish some buckets. Do you do some other graphic intense things at rendertime? Try CPU rendering to see if you could reproduce the error.